# How to fix: Recyclerview not showing in Activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a Recyclerview, where i can display cards.
I've followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YL1VpGBj3R0), wich displays exactly what I want. However this is not what's showing in my application right now.

I've tried to debug the Adapter to see if the data is Empty, but that's not the case

The [classes](https://hastebin.com/beluyajiqe.java) i'm using

The [activity_main](https://hastebin.com/kiheyuridi.xml) i'm using

The [card_view](https://hastebin.com/beluyajiqe.java) i'm using

The cardView also uses a gradient and layout for the button from the Drawable package, but those are probably not relevant.

On startup, the recyclerview is not being showed on my activity.

I expect the layout like the tutorial displays in the beginning of the video.

Comment: no project in github

Comment: your link is broken

Comment: The link doesn't work, and in any case, you should post code here that identifies the problem and not link to it elsewhere.

Comment: Check your model class size and did you define model size in Recycler Adapter getItemCount() method

Comment: I'll show my classes then. Sorry for this

Comment: I've updated the link. The code should be seen in Hastebin right now

Comment: @SchredderBeeren haven't you read the above comment? we won't follow these links. maybe read [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, because this explains how to ask in detail. you'll have this question put on hold, unless providing the least code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, @VasudeVyas already answered my question. My getItemCount() return 0 instead of the list.size(). The problem I feel with asking a question about this is that I use 4 xml stylesheets and 3 classes, so I couldn't specify the problem myself.

Comment: DO NOT add code off-site. Not as screenshots, not on pastebin, not on GitHub, not on <insert paste or code hosting service here>. Paste it into the question, and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put size of your `mData` list in `getItemCount()`:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}
```